# MySql .NET connector returning byte array instead of actual type

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

I have a MySql database and one of the fields is a `GEOMETRY` field. I am using ADO.Net to connect to the database and I am writing data into the field like this:

```
var myGeometry = new MySql.Data.Types.MySqlGeometry(15.3f, 12.9f);
string cmdString = "INSERT INTO `MyTable` (LaunchPoint) VALUES (@val1);";

using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = cmdString;
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameters("@val1", MySqlDbType.Geometry) {Value = myGeometry});

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

This is working fine. It writes the data to the database and if I do a `SELECT` command from MySQL Workbench, I can see the data is there.

The problem I am running into is reading the data back. The data comes back as a `byte[]` instead of a `MySqlGeometry` object. Here is my read code:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandTet = sql;

        connection.Open();
        using (var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter())
        {
            using (var ds = new DataSet())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(ds);

                // Error occurs on the next line
                var geo = (MySqlGeometry) ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LaunchPoint"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An error occurs when I try to load the `geo` variable with the data. The error is telling me it can't cast a byte array into a `MySqlGeometry`. Upon closer look, it does, indeed, seem like the MySQL .NET connector is converting it into a byte array for some reason. I found a similar question about this [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,254127). However, this question has no response and it's like 6 years old. Surely this would have been fixed by now if its a bug.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than cast, new up a new instance of the object using the byte array constructor.

```
public MySqlGeometry(MySqlDbType type, byte[] val)
```

[source](https://github.com/pdonald/mysql-connector-net/blob/master/Source/MySql.Data/Types/MySqlGeometry.cs)

```
var geo = new MySqlGeometry(MySqlDbType.Geometry, ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LaunchPoint"]);
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly. I still think it should work by casting, like all the other data types do. But this is working great. Thank you!

Comment: @Icemanind happy to help!  While it would be nice if there was a cast option, it would need to be added as an explicit operator to the MySqlGeometry class, which the library creators apparently did not see the value in.  The following added to the source of MySqlGeometry would allow for your cast.  public static explicit operator MySqlGeometry (byte[] geometry)
{
    return new MySqlGeometry(MySqlDbType.Geometry, geometry);
}  Of course, this is really just syntac sugar.  At the end of the day it's still newing up a new instance of the class.